Product matrices whose spectral radius are positive and less than 1
First a example
Consider a matrix $G$ whose spectral radius is less than 1, thus there exist a matrix norm such that $\|G\| \leq 1$, we let $\gamma = \|G\|<1$ and
we have that
\begin{align}
      \|G^k\| \leq \|G\|^k =\gamma^k   
\end{align}
using the equivalence of matrix norms we have
\begin{align}             
r_2\|G^k\|_2   \leq\|G^k\|\leq r_1\|G^k\|_2 \to \|G^k\|_2 \leq \Gamma \gamma^k 
\end{align}
where $\Gamma=r_2^{-1}$ is a constant
the equation above show that a fixed matrix G with $\rho(G)\leq1 $ holds a upper bound and the 2-norm of $G^k$ converge.
Now my question is quite common and I cannot obtain the correct consequence. My question is as follows.
There exist a positive matrix set $\{Q_k\}$ and all the matrix have $\rho(Q_k)<1$ and all their eigenvalues are positive.
Then whether we can obtain a similar results that
\begin{align}
\|\prod_{s=1}^k Q_s \|_2 = \|Q_1 Q_2 ...Q_k\|_2 \leq \Gamma \gamma^k \ \ ?
\end{align}
where $\Gamma$ is a constant and $\gamma$ is a constant less than 1.
The main reference book is "Matrix Analysis" composed by Horn.

What exactly do you mean by "a positive matrix set"? Are you saying that each $Q_k$ has positive entries and that the elements $Q_j,Q_k$ are necessarily distinct for $j \neq k$?

If I understood your question correctly then no, we cannot obtain such a result. As a counterexample, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1/2 & 10\\0&1/2},
$$
and define $Q_k$ for even and odd $k$ separately, as follows: for $j = 1,2,3,\dots,$
$$
Q_{2j-1} = \sqrt{\frac{j}{j+1}}A^T, \quad Q_{2j} = \sqrt{\frac{j}{j+1}}A.
$$
Let $\lambda$ denote the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, note that $\lambda \approx 100.49$. Note that $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda}$. For $k = 2j$, we have
$$
\|Q_1Q_2 \cdots Q_{k}\|_2 = \frac{\lambda^{k/2}}{k/2} = \frac 2k (\lambda^{1/2})^k.
$$
For $k = 2j-1$, note that
$$
\|Q_1Q_2 \cdots Q_k Q_{k+1}\|_2 \leq \|Q_1Q_2 \cdots Q_{k}\|_2 \cdot \|Q_{k+1}\| \implies\\
\|Q_1 Q_2 \cdots Q_k\|\geq \frac{\|Q_1Q_2 \cdots Q_k Q_{k+1}\|_2}{\|Q_{k+1}\|} = \frac 2k (\lambda^{1/2})^k \cdot \sqrt{\frac{j+1}j} \cdot \lambda^{-1/2}.
$$
From there, it is straightforward to see that $\left\|\prod_{s=1}^k Q_s\right\|_2$ grows without bound.
If the fact that $Q_k$ has strictly positive entries is important to you, then you could replace $A$ with
$$
\pmatrix{1/2 & 10\\ \epsilon  & 1/2},
$$
where $\epsilon > 0$ is sufficiently small (say, $0.01$). The argument above applies, but the value of $\lambda$ will be different.
